# Issue with removing rows in excel table

Tags: excel, office365, excel-addins

I was working with new office web add-in for excel and manipulating the excel tables programmatically.

There are some strange situations where depending on table location it is not possible to delete the rows of the table.

For example as shown in an image below, when removing row in the first table the error is "This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet."

[image: Error when removing the row in the first table]

In cases below there is no any error, I am not sure what is wrong with first use case.
[image: The case where there is no any error when removing rows]

and this

[image: Other case where there is no any error when removing rows]

Comment: The error message needs to be improved to something like: "it would PARTIALLY move a table on this worksheet". Realign or resize the tables first."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the first case removing one of the rows would move part of the rows of the second table (the first two columns would move up one row). In your other cases removing the row from the first table would only move up empty cells, not affecting the other tables.